# Cannot find class [food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl] for bean with name 'foodDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml];

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm learning Spring and got stuck in an error. Spring is unable to find the defined class in the beans:

```
31-Mar-2018 20:12:44.049 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl] for bean with name 'foodDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1385)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:641)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1007)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1432)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1377)
... 55 more
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean id="foodDAO" class="food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl"/>

    <bean id="foodService" class="food.bill.service.FoodServiceImpl">
        <property name="foodDao" ref="foodDAO"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

FoodDaoImpl:

```
package food.bill.dao;

import food.bill.model.FoodItem;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;


public class FoodDaoImpl implements FoodDao {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(FoodDaoImpl.class);
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<FoodItem> getMenu() {
        List<FoodItem> foodMenu = null;
        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("FoodItem.getMenu");
                 foodMenu = (List<FoodItem>) query.getResultList();
            return foodMenu;
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.info("Error in getting Menu");
        }
        return foodMenu;
    }


    public void createOrder() {

    }
}
```

FoodServiceImpl:

```
package food.bill.service;

import food.bill.dao.FoodDao;
import food.bill.model.FoodItem;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class FoodServiceImpl implements FoodService {

   private FoodDao foodDao;

    public void setFoodDao(FoodDao foodDao) {
        this.foodDao = foodDao;
    }

    public List<FoodItem> getMenu() {
        return this.foodDao.getMenu();
    }
}
```

I've check the output folders and all the files are updated. Tried searching for hours but didn't get any result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the source code of `FoodServiceImpl`

Comment: @lucumt code updated

Answer (score 2):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl] for bean with name 'foodDAO'
>   defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml];
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl

simply means that Spring is trying to *find* the `.class` file for the class   `food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl` in your defined classpath and does not find it.

So please first check if `food.bill.dao.FoodDaoImpl` file is really compiled as .class file and where it is laid in your output file directory.

Comment: I've checked it multiple times and it is present in the output folder.

Comment: which IDE are you using please (eclipse, netbeans, IntelliJ) ?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to double check

1. If you are using Maven or any other build tool try "Maven clean" and check whether its deleting the foodDao.class file or not. If it does then do Maven build after the clean and see whether it fixes the issue or not.
2. If step 1 did not fix the issue try putting the bean definition of foodDAO after the bean definition of foodService in the context.xml (just a thought)

Let me know if the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a *bug within Maven*. I also faced the issus many times. Even when the class is present but is not detected as per error, doing the following worked for me.

**Solution I: Deleting the Java file class from the source package.**

1. Create the backup of the code and delete the Java file from the source package.
2. Add the file back to the source package by creating the new file with the same
   Java Class code that you faced error for.

**Solution II: Move the Java file class from one source package to other.**

1. Move the Java file class from one source package to other.
2. Then  put the Java file class back to its original package.

I hope either of the soluton will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is:

- My Eclipse project is running OK all the time
- Sometimes, it will gie me the same error message
- All I did is to delete all files in "target", then re-compile again. It will work.